# Correct way to use nginx as a web cache

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use nginx as a web cache (and failing to do so).

My system is an Ubuntu 16.04 server where nginx is a reverse proxy for a gunicorn web server (it's a Django application).

To configure web caching, I added the following lines at the top of my `virtual host` file (the one in `sites-available`):

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=static_cache:10m max_size=90m;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$is_args$args";
proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m;
proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
```

Next, inside the main `server` scope, I have the following snippet (where I've injected the caching directives):

```
location @https_proxy_to_app {
    proxy_cache static_cache;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;
    add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    # additional proxy parameters
    include proxy_params;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
```

This doesn't yeild cache HITS or MISSES when I try to curl static asset uris (which is the only way to test whether the cache is working or not). Ergo, the caching is not operational. Here's what I mean:

Trying `curl -X GET -I https://example.com/static/css/my_app.css` yields:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:05:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 26597
Last-Modified: Fri, 03 Jan 2020 14:23:59 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
ETag: "5e0f4e7f-67e5"
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

This is problematic because it was supposed to include `X-Proxy-Cache: HIT` or `X-Proxy-Cache: MISS`. Please help me in diagnosing the issue.

---

Following are all my `location` blocks (in order of appearance):

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|svg|woff|ttf|eot)$ {

    root /home/ubuntu/app/myproj/;
    access_log off;
    error_log off;

}

# shows number of connections at https://example.com/status_nginx
location /status_nginx {
    stub_status on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
}

location / {

    limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 20;
    limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=10 nodelay;

    limit_req_log_level warn;

    #proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffers 24 4k;
    proxy_buffer_size 2k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 8k;

    try_files $uri @https_proxy_to_app;
}

location @https_proxy_to_app {

    proxy_cache static_cache;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;
    add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    # additional proxy parameters
    include proxy_params;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the URI /static is being caught by the @https_proxy_to_app location where the cache definitions are set?

Comment: @Marcel: I see. I've actually added all the `location` blocks in my config within the question. Can you have a quick look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.css` file is served using the following block in your configuration:

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|svg|woff|ttf|eot)$
    root /home/ubuntu/app/myproj/;
    access_log off;
    error_log off;
}
```

This means nginx is sending the file directly, without using upstream server to process the request. This means there is no caching performed.

If you remove `.css` extension from the list AND if your `root` doesn't point to directory where this CSS file can be found, then the request will go via `proxy_pass` to the upstream server.

Then the response will be cached provided that the upstream server sets suitable HTTP cache headers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Tero. I'll tinker around with our suggestion in a bit and get back to you.

Comment: Actually, I do need one clarification straight up. What's wrong with adding `proxy_cache static_cache` straight in  `location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|svg|woff|ttf|eot)`

Comment: There is no point in caching static resources that are already available as files. For testing it is OK.

Comment: So your implication is: if I'm already using the pattern where nginx is directly serving static resources via `location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|svg|woff|ttf|eot)`, there's no performance advantage to be gained from using the `proxy_cache` directive?

Comment: Yes, it is not useful for static files. It is useful for dynamic content provided by your backend application.

Comment: For static files the ETag of the previous request is sent by the browser as If-not-modified-since and only if changed it will request, otherwise the webserver answers with 304 not modified and the browser use its local cached copy.

Comment: One thing I'm struggling with, in case you can help. If I remove `css` from `location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|svg|woff|ttf|eot)`, the `css` stops loading entirely. Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: You need to look into your web application logs, and see why it doesn't serve the .css file.